# Is it possible to create two identical routes with a different param name using Fastify?

Tags: node.js, routes, fastify

In my application, I would like to have two routes that match the following paths

```
fastify.get('/thing/:id', async () => {})
fastify.get('/thing/:name', async () => {})
```

I tried giving the ':id' path a regex, but Fastify still recognized them as duplicate routes.  Is it possible to accomplish this aside from running a regex in the handler to determine if it is an id or a name?

EDIT: I failed to mention that I am familiar with the Fastify documentation. I was hoping to discover something that is not currently documented.

A nice alternative would be if it were possible to declare alternate params at the same path level and to have the schema determine which param applies.  For example:
`'/thing/:id|:name'` and then have the params schema or be the determining factor, or separate regexs in the route like, `'/thing/:id()|:name()'`.

Anyway, would be cool.

Comment: No, that's not possible. How would routing be able to distinguish whether in  `/thing/foo` the `foo` is an `id` or a `name`? How would you distinguish?

Comment: @derpirscher, honestly it seems pretty simple to me.  Set up a route schema with regex pattern matching and if it matches the first pattern it follows that route, if it matches the second route pattern it follows that route, basically the same I am doing within the handler.  Even without a schema, using different regex patterns on the routes seems like it should have worked.  Oh well, (shrug).

Comment: Mutually exclusive regular expressions.

Comment: The problem is, that is quite hard decide whether two regex are mutually exclusive or not. It may be pretty obvious for a human that `/^[0-9]+$/` and `/^[a-z]+$/` are mutually exclusive. But it's not that easy to do that algorithmically

Comment: But it may be possible to define and use a custom constraint for your id and name value https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#constraints

Comment: Thanks.  I had read about that, but I didn't want to put the onus on the consumers of my API to have to send the constraints.  I think just evaluating the regex in the route handler seems like the best option for now.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Each has to be different from other somehow. But what you can do is Route Prefixing.

Like this

// server.js

```
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.register(require('./routes/v1/things'), { prefix: '/v1' })
fastify.register(require('./routes/v2/things'), { prefix: '/v2' })

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 })
```

// routes/v1/things.js

```
module.exports = function (fastify, opts, done) {
  fastify.get('/thing/:id', handler_v1)
  done()
}
```

// routes/v2/things.js

```
module.exports = function (fastify, opts, done) {
  fastify.get('/thing/:name', handler_v2)
  done()
}
```

Fastify will not complain because you are using the same name for two different routes, because at compilation time it will handle the prefix automatically (this also means that the performance will not be affected at all!).

Now your clients will have access to the following routes:

```
/v1/thing/:id
/v2/thing/:name
```

You can do this as many times as you want, it also works for nested register, and route parameters are supported as well.

You can read more about fastify routes [here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/).

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I forgot to specify that I am already quite familiar with the Fastify documentation.  I was looking for something that is not currently documented.  Thanks anyway, though!